# Python _add_ method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to override `_add_` method. I am getting error :
Point3 = Point1 + Point2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Point' and 'Point'

What am I missing? Please help. This was my first Python class.

```
from math import sqrt                
            
class Point(object):

    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __str__(self):
        return "%i,%i,%i"%(self.x, self.y, self.z)
    
    def _add_(self, other):
        TotalX = self.x + other.x
        TotalY = self.y + other.y
        TotalZ = self.z + other.z
        return Point(TotalX, TotalY, TotalZ)

    def Distance(self, other):
        val =0
        val = ((self.x - other.x)**2+ (self.y - other.y)**2 + (self.z - other.z)**2)
        return val 

print ("Just defined method")    
Point1= Point(x=4, y=2, z=9)
Point2= Point(x=5, y=3, z=10)
Point3 = Point1 + Point2
```

Thanks,
Shruti.

Comment: Your indenting is broken, please fix.

Comment: The indentation for the method `Distance` is not correct... Please Correct that by editing your question

Comment: Thanks Stephen and Harshit - That indentation issue was only while pasting it here. Alexander pointed out my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `__add__`, not `_add_`. All magic methods in Python, such as for addition, use **two** leading underscores and **two** trailing underscores. For a detailed reference on the Python data model, including all documented magic methods, please see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I wasted 1 hour in  this error :(

Comment: @ShrutiSinghal If I've solved your question, please mark the question as answered. Glad to help.